# Disabling mouse-over highlighting of toolbar buttons (winapi)

Tags: windows, winapi, toolbar, win32gui

Is there any way (well, I'm assuming there must be) to disable mouse-over highlighting for a toolbar in XP? I'm just making standard Win32 calls for my application's GUI, through Common Lisp. Alternatively is it possible to implement custom highlighting?

Many thanks,
ChrisM

Comment: but why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is called hot-tracking and is performed for flat style toolbars. If you want to disable it then remove the [TBSTYLE_FLAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) style.

Comment: Thank you David, I've managed to do that now. I wanted to do it because I'm using a toolbar to implement a set of audio playback controls in my application, which I felt needed a different visual and interaction style to the main toolbar.

Comment: If this answers the question then you could consider accepting it